# ADO OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns) fails for the odd excel file

Tags: c++, excel, ado

I have code that reads column headers from MS Excel files using C++ & ADO. I got this one Excel file from someone for which the OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns) command fails (The error is: 0x800A0CB3: "Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation"). To narrow the problem, I removed all data from the file & deleted all columns except column A. If I delete column A as well, OpenSchema succeeds. Otherwise, it fails. I compared column A to other columns using the excel CELL function: format, protection, contents: but there is no difference.

In any case, OpenSchema(adSchemaTables) does NOT fail.

This is an excerpt of the C++ code I use, built with VS2010:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado28.tlb" no_namespace rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")

_ConnectionPtr pCon;
pCon.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection))
pCon->Open(connStr, "", "", NULL)
_RecordsetPtr pSchema = NULL;
pSchema = pCon->OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns);
```

This is a link to the faulty excel file:
[workbook.xls](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2BtmmWMZ5T9TUxFWS13T0tWREk)

I use MS Excel 2010.

To reproduce: run the code on unchanged workbook.xls - fails. Delete column A - succeeds.

Any ideas are welcome,

Thank you

Comment: By any chance is column A header ID? There is a bug.

Comment: No. Actually all data was removed including headers..